# I am using `fcm` gem to send push notification it is working fine for android but not for IOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am developing Backend where notification need to be send to IOS devises. I have configured properly APN certificates password and everything on Firebase but still sometime notification is going to IOS from simple script but sometime it does not go. But on Ruby on rails it never goes. I have checked and including all files properly. Still getting this issue.

following is script I made for sending notification, it grabs devise token from user table.

```
user = User.find(86)
  devises = user.devises
     devises.each do |d|
     response = send_notification(title, body, d, action, type)
  end

  fcm = FCM.new("my_fcm_server_key_log_key_from_firebase")
  registration_ids = ["#{devise.token.to_s}"]
  options = { "data": {
      "title": title,
      "body": body,
      "msg_action": action,
      "msg_type": type,
    },
       "badge": 1,
       "alert": "dasdas",
       "sound": "default" 
}
  response = fcm.send(registration_ids, options)
    puts response.inspect
```

Response come successful, but still it does not reach to mobile phone, but when I hard code everything and use simple script it goes properly from server and local system too, but in Ruby on rails it is not going. on Android it is working perfectly without any issue. Even on simple script IOS after few hours stop working using simple ruby script too.

Please let me know if you have any working sample for ruby on rails.

Comment: It is not related to Rails issue, Check ios config on firebase and in ios app

Comment: when I am using firebase to send notification it is going correctly from their dashboard.

Comment: I am having the same issue, working from firebase console, but wont send ios from rails. did you ever figure out the problem?

Comment: I put answer what I have done to resolve it issue, but it was mostly test and try, no issue in library, but just format of push notification, and developer uploaded on FCM.

Answer (score 2):

I have to upload certification files on FCM for IOS app, it is usally developer license p12 or p8 files which needed to be uploaded on the your new app project.

I have to change format which I was sending for IOS, now I have place condition if it is android than there is different format, where I have IOS than I have put different format with very minor changes.

```
if devise.platform == "iOS"
   options = { "notification": {
     "title": title,
     "body": body,
     "msg_action": action,
     "msg_type": type,
      },
        "badge": 1,
        "alert": "dasdas",
        "sound": "default" }
    else
      options = {
        "data": {
        "title": title,
        "body": body,
        "msg_action": action,
        "msg_type": type,
        "click_action": ".DashBoardActivity",
        },
      }
  end
```

Another point to note is you have check you app log, sometime when app is not running, you get push notification, but if app is running then you won't get anything on display, but behind scene you are getting push notification, which you have to handle using your app codings of IOS. I have added `badge, alert, sound` these are for specific to IOS.

Answer is given to explain comments posted @Brad.